# How to check for a specific count of letters in a row in a String Java

Tags: java, regex

I want to check if my String contains words with a specific length

```
String s = "ab a abc ac";
if(s.contains(/*any words with 3 or more letters which would be 'abc'*/){
   //doSomething
}
```

Is there a way to do this in regex or with a simple method? Similar to

```
s.contains("[a-za-za-z]"); //or
s.contains().lettersInARow(3);
```

What I want is to find these and throw an Error when something longer than 2 characters is found

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> or with a simple method

```java
String s = "ab a abc ac";
long countWordsWithAtLeastThreeCharacters = 
    Arrays.stream( s.split( " " ) )
    .filter( word -> input.codePoints().toArray().length > 3 )
    .count() ;
```

I added the FACE WITH MEDICAL MASK to demonstrate that this works with all characters. Avoid using `char` as it is physically incapable of representing most characters.

---

Be aware that in some languages what you may perceive as one "letter" is actually a combination of *two* characters, a letter followed by a "combining diacritical". Example [here](https://ideone.com/n0dcRT). Discussion [here](https://gregtatum.com/writing/2021/diacritical-marks/).

Comment: Love the COVID safe programming.  But this won't work with anti-vaxers 'cos they don't have their own emoji.  (Let's start a conspiracy theory about that :-) )